# how to continuously rotate an image in the video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to make a very simple video of an image being continuously rotated, but the 2.6 [manual on this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Effects) seems to be outdated. In 2.70 there is no rotation start/end but just a constant angle. Could someone share how this is done in current versions?

not sure if this needs to be clarified but i'm importing the image in VSE as a strip (Shift-A -> Image), not splashing it on a plane and trying to capture that with the camera ... or something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a transform effect strip then keyframe the start and end with rotation changes. Otherwise you can add a couple small rotation keyframes to check speed then add a Cycle modifier to the f-curve of the .blend that extends the animation out past the keyframes. 
[f-curve modifiers 2.6 wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Graph/FModifiers)

> Cycles mode - Repeat with Offset
>   : Repeats the curve data, but offsets the value of the first point to the value of the last point each cycle.

Comment: when i try to add a keyframe in any of the predefined Rotation related keying sets i get the error: "No suitable context info for active keying set"
I tried defining a new keying set, but the Target ID-Block list doesn't contain strip or sequence as an option. i'm probably missing something basic here.
the Cycles modifier suggestion i don't understand so didn't try it.

Comment: inserting the keyframe is done by right clicking on the rotation field in the transformation strip properties [this](http://screencast.com/t/PeY5nH9Vq) screencast shows it for scaling.